# EF code first: using Linq with many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I am using MVC 4 with EF code first approach. I have two simple objects. These are their POCO classes:

```
public class Activity
{
        //Primitive Properties
        [HiddenInput]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int LengthInMinutes { get; set; }

        public string AdditionalInfo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Archive { get; set; }

        //Navigation Properties
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual ActivitySet ActivitySet { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
        //Primitive Properties
        [HiddenInput]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Archive { get; set; }

        //Navigation Properties
        public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have generic list of activities which I iterate through using foreach loop. While looping I want to write a name for each Company related to the activity from the list. This is a code I came up with:

```
@foreach (Activity a in Model)
{
    <p>@a.Companies.Where(d => d.Activities.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Id == a.Id)).Single()</p>
}
```

Unfortunately it gives me compilation error when I build the project. How can I then access details of the elements with many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like so:

```
@foreach (Activity a in Model)
{
    <p>@string.Join(",", a.Companies.Select(c => c.Title))</p>
}
```

It should give a list of all company titles of a given activity separated by a comma.